# vscode settings sync with github account not working

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

i am using arch linux and have installed the `vscode` with source downloaded from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).
using these commands:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/vscode-files/;
tar -C /tmp/vscode-files -xf vscode.tar.gz;
sudo rm -rf /opt/vscode;
sudo cp -r /tmp/vscode-files/* /opt/vscode;
sudo ln -sf /opt/vscode/bin/code /usr/bin/code
```

all looks good but when trying to login with `Turn on settings sync` with `github` account, nothing happens.

i have tried checking `journalctl` messages and network on `vscode` developer tools, but nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

###### 1. The `vscode` sync wouldn't open the link in the browser

it was `firefox` in my case, however, it worked with `chrome`. and it looks like the problem is the default application for opening links like the one `vscode` generates, so just having chrome will work, otherwise go throw setting the default for that type, which I didn't in this case.

###### 2. After authentication, browser won't redirect to `vscode`

create a desktop file at `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications` named `vscode.desktop` with following content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=vscode
Exec=/usr/bin/code --open-url %U
Icon=code
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/vscode;
```

and then run the following command to set th mime type

```
xdg-mime default vscode.desktop x-scheme-handler/vscode
```

and then try again.

note: in `.desktop` file, change the `Exec` line based on where your executable is.

Comment: thank you, this is a great answer and explanation

Comment: happy that it helped! <3